# Flutter MobX: Should I use @action just only for changing the existing value?

Tags: flutter, dart, mobx

I'm building an app which have a **Login page**, and I wanna call a **login method** when the user taps the button. But the question is:

> Should I use the `@action` just only for changing the existing value?

Or can I do something like this:

```dart
@action
void login() {
  ... // here is the business logic
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mobx is a **state** management, so it **is** all about managing state.

State is data that changes over time, so here making mobx action it should make a real state/data change otherwise it should be a normal function not a state action.